# Enabling scrollbars in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have HTML document based on twitter Bootstrap, which is like:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<nav></nav>
<div class="container" id="main"></div>
<footer class="footer"></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that `<nav>` is 50px high and `<footer>` is 20px high.
I want my div to be 20px from the navbar and 20px from the footer. Also, I want scrollbars to appear only in div, not on the whole page, so I have a CSS stylesheet like this:

```
 body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#main.container {;
    overflow: auto;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is, that to use overflow:auto I have to define div height and I need this div to fill the screen.
Can someone tell me how can i do that?

Thanks for help,
Cyanide

Answer (score 0):

Position the container absolute and give it 'top' and 'bottom' so that you do not need to use height!

```
#main.container {
    overflow: auto;

  position: absolute;
  background:red;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 20px;
}
```

Something like this - [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dusani/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: This will not fill the screen (which is presumably the aim)

Comment: Yes, I want div to fill the screen.

Comment: It would be ok, but this destroys the boostrap settings. After setting position:absolute div sticks to the left corner and it should be vertically centered.

Comment: @Cyanide That should be fixable by setting 'left' and giving margin as auto. Can you create a fiddle and post it here so that I can help you out better!

Comment: I don't know why, but in fiddle it is working fine :( https://jsfiddle.net/2m5oyhw5/

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use absolute positioning on the container.

Something like:

```
#main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 70px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Whats the second option?

Comment: @Aley: 100% height, negative margins and padding (which I personally hate)

Comment: It would be ok, but this destroys the boostrap settings. After setting position:absolute div sticks to the left corner and it should be horizontally centered.

Comment: @Cyanide: I think you mean horizontally centered :) It depends on where you nest the containers. I use fixed header, footer and scrolling containers in bootstrap. Perhaps you can provide a more complete JSFiddle so I can demonstrate?

Comment: I don't know why, but in Fiddle it is working fine :(

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setHeight() {
    windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
    windowHeight = windowHeight - 110;
    $('#main.container').css('height', windowHeight);
  };
  setHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setHeight();
  });
});
```

But thanks everybody for answers.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you do not want to define the height in order to fit any screen size.

You could set the heigh, [calculate the size of the screen with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window)
then set the new heigh (screen - nav - footer), like

```
document.getElementById("container").style.height = new_height;
```

`new_height` must be a string.